# i have query and i want to insert it into database through vba

Tags: database, excel, vba

but it insert string into database show in image. when i remove " " then show error invalid column name .

```
query = "select code from info"
conn.Execute "insert into dbo.Customers (AccountNo,Amount,code) values ('" & AccountNo & "', '" & Amount & "', query)"
```

[image]

Comment: You have to execute the query as you did with the insert into. Depending on which sql server your using you can insert a subquery in the insert.

Comment: i am using sql server 2008

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, if your using mssql

```
query = "select top 1 code from info"
conn.Execute "insert into dbo.Customers (AccountNo,Amount,code) " & _
             "values ('" & AccountNo & "', '" & Amount & "', ("& query &"))"
```

it will execute the subquery inside query

Comment: what if you try to execute `insert into dbo.customers(accountno, amount, code) values ('1111', '111', (select top 1 code from info))` directly in the editor of sql management studio of your sql2008? which error comes out ?